# Import a propertie file in QSH Command - iseries

Tags: java, command, ibm-midrange

is there a way, that i could load a propertie file in a QSH Command.

The Problem is my System is running on a Java 1.4 Version and my Programm is only running in a Java 1.6 Version. So i wrote a propertie files that says, take the 1.6 version but i absulutly have no plan how to implemnt it in my code..

```
  java -cp "Test.jar:lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

The name of the Properie file is Java_Version.properties

Do you have any solution ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a properties file to load with the environment variable [QIBM_JAVA_PROPERTIES_FILE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaha/sysprop.htm).

```
QIBM_JAVA_PROPERTIES_FILE=/path/to/myproperties.properties java -cp "Test.jar:lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

In addition properties in a file named [SystemDefault.properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaha/sdpropf.htm) will be automatically loaded if it exists in the user home directory.

Here are some links to additional documentation that may be useful:

- [Installing Java on your IBM i server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaha/rzahainstalljdk.htm)
- [Support for multiple Java Development Kits (JDKs)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaha/multjdk.htm)
- [Java system properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaha/sysprop.htm)
- [SystemDefault.properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaha/sdpropf.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Use the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`  On IBM i 7.1, I would specify:

```
JAVA_HOME='/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk60/64bit'
export JAVA_HOME
java -version
```

IBM Support Document [N1011999](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011999) *Support Java Versions by Operating System Release* describes the JAVA_HOME settings for various operating system releases.